# wglCreateContextAttribsARB is undefined

Tags: opengl, windows

I've just downloaded the latest headers from the OpenGL registry and included them in my project. I am attempting to create an OpenGL 3+ context. Every tutorial/resource has used wglCreateContextAttribsARB to do this. However, this does not seemed to be defined in the headers I have.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include "glcorearb.h"
#include "glext.h"
#include "wglext.h"
...
wglCreateContextAttribsARB = // Not recognised
(PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC) wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB"); // Recognised (Why this and not the function name?)
```

The closest existing function is wglCreateContext, which I don't believe is what I want.

In the wglext.h header, there is this though:

```
typedef HGLRC (WINAPI * PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC) (HDC hDC, HGLRC hShareContext, const int *attribList);
#ifdef WGL_WGLEXT_PROTOTYPES
HGLRC WINAPI wglCreateContextAttribsARB (HDC hDC, HGLRC hShareContext, const int *attribList);
#endif
```

And that can get me the function, but is defining WGL_WGLEXT_PROTOTYPES really the "correct" way to do what I want?

I haven't been able to find any information on the issue, what is the correct procedure? And where can I find information on changes/problems like these?

I'm not interested in using any extension loading libraries such as GLEW to handle this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define that function pointer yourself. It doesn't exist in the OpenGL implementation that ships with Windows and this is why you have a problem on that line labeled `// Not recognised`.

#### At the very least, you need something to the effect:

```
PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB =
  (PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC) wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");
```

But be aware that you have to create and destroy a render context just to load and use this extension. It is rather convoluted considering the whole point of this extension is to create a render context. That's just how WGL works unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Strange though, as I'm sure I've done it without defining the functions myself in previous projects. I thought these functions has been defined in the included headers. It may have been the case that I had GLEW or such being loaded in my previous projects and not been aware of it, or as familiar with what they were doing. I can act of this though, thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, if you use GLEW you don't have to do any dirty work like this. That's why it's so popular ;)

Comment: I'm well aware of it's usefulness. At the moment, I'm just trying to learn every aspect that I can, and developing my own framework in which I'd like complete control over the loading process, rather than have it abstracted for me. For getting quick projects up and running, I'm more than happy to use GLEW. :)

Answer (score 1):

your trying to find that EP(entry point) - and its also in GLX(linux)...

PGLXContext:^GLXCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC;
    GLXCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC=procedure (PDisplay, Fbc, ctx, Bool, intPtr);

I believe is the correct Pascal translation.
GLX_Context cant be an assigned anything AND something else...In the C- it appears to be.